# Запуск Activity из метода

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть метод в `MainActivity`:

```
public void getPositionEdit(int position) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, addNote.class);

    intent.putExtra("position", position);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("notes", array);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
```

Есть адаптер, в котором прослушиваются нажатия на компоненты `RecyclerView`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.mTextView.setText(array.get(position));

    holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)

                    MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
                    ma.getPositionEdit(position);


        }
    });
}
```

После нажатие на компонент, должна считываться его позиция и передаваться в метод `MainActivity`, в котором будет запускать новое `Activity`. Как правильно нужно прописать, чтобы работало правильно.

Answer (score 2):

лучше всего дабавить слушателя

примерно так:

```
Activity implements ItemClickListener {

/////
adapterRececlerView.setClickListener(this);

///////
@Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, addNote.class);
intent.putExtra("position", position);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("notes", array);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

часть кода адаптера:

```
public class AdapterImageRV extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterImageRV.ViewHolder> {


    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;



 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);           

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

///////////////

public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Объявляете интерфейс:

```
public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {
    void onItemClicked(int position);
}
```

Реализуете этот интерфейс в активити:

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(int position){
        // some actions
    }
}
```

Добавляете поле и сеттер в адаптер:

```
public class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SomeViewHolder> {
    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener mOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener;

    // ...

    public void setListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener onRecyclerViewItemClickListener) {
        mOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener = onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

При создании адаптера устанавливаете листнер:

```
SomeAdapter someAdapter = new SomeAdapter();
someAdapter.setListener(this);
```

И далее из адаптера вызываете метод `onItemClicked(...)`:

```
if (mOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener != null) {
    mOnRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClicked(position);
}
```

PS. Писал на коленке, но суть, думаю, ясна.

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали новый объект активити, он поместился в новую ячейку в памяти, но, при этом, т.к. методы жизненнго цикла не были вызваны, то оно всё полностью неработающее.

Вам нужно получать уже действующий экземпляр активити. Например, скастовав контекст к нему.

```
MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) v.getContext();
ma.getPositionEdit(position);
```

А ещё лучше - реализовать в активити интейрфейс, прокинуть его в адаптер и в нужный момент его метод дёрнуть.