# Обработчик нажатия на item в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Есть список RecyclerVie с элементами состоящими из CardView. Как реализовать обработчик нажатий на элемент RecyclerView? При нажатии на элемент мне нужно открывать второе активити и передавать ему id записи из БД

Comment: Есть кто-нибудь?

Comment: ранее уже давал ответ на подобный вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691268/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-activity-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/691272#691272

Comment: Попробовал ваш метод, он работает но не совсем так как мне нужно. Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на элемент REcyclerview передавался ID записи из БД, а не ID самого item

Answer (score 4):

Считая, что у вас адаптер такой:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>
```

Надо завести что-то типа:

```
  private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.myview, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}
```

Сам кликер:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    int itemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(view);
    String item = mList.get(itemPosition);
    //blah-blah
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю что это все нужно писать в адаптере?

Comment: Я создал интерфейс MyOnClickListener с методом onClick и когда в адаптере пишу так private final OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new MyOnClickListener();  то ругается компилятор и говорит что не может быть инициаизирован

Comment: Вы должны создать не интерфейс а класс реализующий интерфейс `OnClickListener`. Либо при объявлении добавить анонимную реализацию

Comment: как это сделать(

Comment: @Кокосовый я никогда (или очень редко) даю полный ответ, я только указываю путь куда двигаться, дальше уже сами

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас будет необходимость узнавать о клике по элементу списка из Activity/Fragment. В таком случае лучше создать интерфейс, который позволит вам получать обратную связь от адаптера списка.
Интерфейс может иметь примерно такой вид:

```
public interface ListInteractor {
  void onItemClicked(int position);
}
```

Соответственно в Activity/Fragment вы реализуете этот интерфейс, и выполняете все что нужно в методе `onItemClicked()`

В конструктор адаптера добавляете параметр типа интерфейса `ListInteractor`:

```
MyAdapter(List<Item> dataset, ListInteractor interactor) {
...    
this.interactor = interactor;
}
```

После чего, добавляете обработчик на вашу вьюху, и дергаете метод интерактора, чтобы прокинуть ивент в Activity/Fragment, где уже решаете как на него реагировать:

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    ...
    holder.view.setOnClickListener(view -> interactor.onItemClicked(position));
    ...
}
```

Comment: И таким образом я буду знать Id записи, на которую нажал? Т.е. мне не нужно знать ID самого Itemа, а нужно знать Id записи, которая я вывожу из БД в Recyclerview и получив этот Id передать в другое активити и там уже с ним работать

Comment: Собственно в методе onBindViewHolder я могу узнать ID этого элемента. Можно ли его допустим как-то передать в другое активити

Comment: В этом как раз главная цель интерактора. Мы определяем интерфейс так как нам удобно. То есть мы можем добавить любые параметры в метод `onItemClicked()`, и, соответственно, передавать любые данные в активити/фрагмент

Comment: например, можно вместо параметра `position` передавать параметр `long id` или даже `Item clickedItem`

Comment: А интерфейс в адаптер нужно добавлять?

Comment: Если вы про реализацию, то нет. Только активити/фрагмент в которых вы создаете адаптер должны реализовывать этот интерфейс. А если вы про добавления поля интерфейса в адаптере, то однозначно да, так как вам потом нужно будет к нему обращаться в обработчике нажатия.

Comment: holder.view.setOnClickListener(view -> interactor.onItemClicked(position));  в этой строке вместо view что мне написать?

Comment: ничего, это лямбда. это просто синтаксический сахар. как вы параметр назовете - так он и будет называться. это сокращение от `new OnClickListener(View view)`, где `view` - тот же параметр

Comment: стоп. вы наверное не про параметр в лямбде, а про поле в `ViewHolder`. только сейчас дошло. вместо него вы просто подставляете имя поля вьюхи из вашего `ViewHolder`, на которой вы собираетесь ловить нажатие